# how I can let shop manger read and write only one field in woo commerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to let shop manger access (read & write) only one field on order detail dishoard.
How I can disable other field?

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in wordpress which manage to select very detailed permissions: https://pl.wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/
There is Plan B, I call it Jewish Method: There is a function in wordpress `get_role( string $role )`. You can edit function when these fields are being rendered for individual roles